# There are so many errors using function and struct in c

Tags: c

I have already asked my friend to help me figure out where is the problem but it's not working.
I'm using a separate header.h, function.c, and main.c
There are too many errors and I can't type all of them here.

So this is the code, I hope someone can help me because I am going to use this program for my final project
header.h :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define T_anak 200000
#define T_kes 1000000
#define T_makan 20000
struct date {
    int hari,bulan,tahun;
};

struct pegawai 
{
    int nip,jum_anak,jum_kk, gol;
    char nama[30];
    struct date lahir;
};

void fungsiInputpegawai();
```

fucntion.c :

```
#include "header.h"
void fungsiInputpegawai()
{
    struct pegawai data;
    printf("Silakan Masukan data Pegawai\n");
    printf("-> Nama                    : ");
    fgets(data.nama, sizeof data.nama, stdin);
    printf("-> NIP                     : ");
    scanf("%d",&data.nip);
    printf("-> Golongan                : ");
    scanf("%d",&data.gol);
    printf("-> Jumlah Anggota Keluarga : ");
    scanf("%d",&data.jum_kk);
    printf("-> Jumlah Anak             : ");
    scanf("%d",&data.jum_anak);
    scanf("-> Masukan Tanggal Lahir (dd-mm-yyyy) : ");
    scanf("%d-%d-%d",&data.lahir.hari,
                     &data.lahir.bulan,
                     &data.lahir.tahun);
    FILE*fp;
    fp=fopen("Data_pegawai.txt","a");
        fprintf(fp,"\nNama Pegawai          : %s\n",data.nama);
        fprintf(fp,"NIP                     : %d\n",data.nip);
        fprintf(fp, "Golongan               : %d\n",data.gol);
        fprintf(fp,"Jumlah Anggota Keluarga : %d\n",data.jum_kk);
        fprintf(fp,"Jumlah Anak            : %d\n",data.jum_anak);
        fprintf(fp,"Tanggal Lahir           : %d-%d-%d\n",data.lahir.hari,data.lahir.bulan,data.lahir.tahun);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

main.c :

```
#include "header.h"
#include "fungsi.c"

int main (void){
    fungsiInputpegawai();
    return(0);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: don't include .c file

Comment: Start with the very first error *or warning* reported by your compiler.  Fix that, then more on to the next.  You will likely find that the actual number of fixes you need to apply is smaller, maybe much smaller, than the number of diagnostic messages, as one (correct) fix will sometimes clear multiple diagnostics.

Comment: As presently posed, however, your question is too broad.  If you want help with your program then you need to specify a *particular* problem, including the nature of the problem and how to reproduce it.

Comment: Start with the first, then second, and then the next. Work down each and every error until there's one that you don't understand at all. And then you can ask your question. It's not uncommon for a C program to have a dozen errors on its first draft, even for seasoned programers. Fixing bugs by yourself is the only way you can learn

Comment: You want to collect a lot of information about your public employees ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You have `header.h` included multiple times without an include guard.

You first include it in `fungsi.c`.  You then include it in `main.c`, which also includes `fungsi.c`.  So everything in `header.h` appears twice, resulting in multiple definition errors.

Put include guards into your header as follows:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define T_anak 200000
#define T_kes 1000000
#define T_makan 20000
struct date {
    int hari,bulan,tahun;
};

struct pegawai 
{
    int nip,jum_anak,jum_kk, gol;
    char nama[30];
    struct date lahir;
};

void fungsiInputpegawai();

#endif
```

The first time this include file is encountered, it defines the `HEADER_H` macro and the contents of the file are included.  Then if it is included a second time, `#ifndef HEADER_H` evaluates to false, so the remainder of the file (i.e. the struct definitions, variable and function declarations, etc.) is not processed and you don't have duplicate definitions.

Also, it's bad practice to include one .c file in another.  What you should be doing is compiling main.c and fungsi.c separately, then linking them.

So remove `#include "fungsi.c"` from main.c and compile as follows:

```
gcc -c -Wall -Wextra fungsi.c
gcc -c -Wall -Wextra main.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o my_program main.o fungsi.o
```

Comment: Correct answer, good gcc examples. If you have time you could explain what the include guard does. It may also be noteworthy that it's usually not needed for simpler programs following the include strategy you suggest (e.g. do not include C files ;-) ).